# How to find absolute path within a project

Tags: java, path, absolute

I have a mavenproject (java).

Now there is a file in that project. A file, NOT an object of the class File. (txt, actually) In the end, this file will be bundled within the jar. I want to use that during the execution of the project and I do need the absolute path to that file.
Of course that differs depending on the computer I am using.
If we were talking about a File object, I would simply find the absolutepath by using myfile.getAbsolutePath.

Is there also a way to find the path in that case?

Comment: When deployed, will the file reside in a jar, war, rar o ear file?

Answer (score 3):

> this file will be bundled within the jar.

That *file* is not a stand alone file on the filesystem anymore. It has no unique filesystem path which points it exclusively.

Its part of a packaged file(similar to a zip) after packaging. That is the main reason methods like [class.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and [classLoader.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) are provided.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection comes to the rescue. You can do this:

```
java.net.URL url = <your class name>.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();

java.io.File file = new java.io.File(url.toURI());
```

`file.toString()` will give you the absolute path. But use sparingly as there are security implications when using `getProtectionDomain()`: check it works on all your platforms.

Comment: Which class would be used in "your class name"?

Comment: Any class that you know to be in the jar, or the class associated with the file that has the name YourClassName.class.

Comment: Well, I get a maven exception. I was thinking of maybe directly using locate on linux systems to get that - is there a similar method for windows=

Comment: That's odd. I do this on Windows.

Comment: Sorry my fault I get an exception when I try rocketboy's suggestion. Howsoever, doing it your way I do get a path which I know to be not correct.

Comment: My fault again, I forgot the toString. It does work...however, as you just told me it might not work on all platforms: could you specify?

Comment: @newnewbie; I don't know for sure: I believe that getProtectionDomain() can fail if there is a security manager running. Google that function for more details.

Comment: Of course.However, I get a path to a certain folder in a project that way (target/classes), but is there a way to specify for a folder with a specific file in it?

Comment: You mean something like `java.nio.file.Path path = file.toPath().getParent()` ?

Comment: No I mean the path to an uncompiled txt-file within the jar. That path is NOT compiled but the hints here get me the path to target/classes which is not where my file, which is NOT a file object, is